# Hiding contents without hiding the div?

Tags: css, html

This may be the simplest question ever, but try as I might I simply couldn't figure it out. I'm working on a website right now and I wish to use as few `<div>` elements as possible to keep the HTML pretty and easy to edit. At the moment I essentially have:

```
<html doctype etc etc>
<head>
    <title and meta tags>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="body"></div>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Very simple and elegant, yes? However the client wants their header to consist of a single large image which contains their company name and logo. So my options were pretty clear - either use an `<img>` tag, or set the `background-image` property on the header `<div>`. However then I got to thinking about SEO. For Google's sake it would be nice if the header `<div>` contained an `<h1>` element with her website's title, but then this element would have to be hidden so that human users only see the background image.

Although if you were to use the `display:none;` css property then the entire `<div>` disappears, including the background. Is there a good way to hide the contents of a `<div>` without hiding the `<div>` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to apply the hide on the H1 itself?

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Company title</h1>
</div>
```

Your style would be: `#header h1{display:none;visibility:hidden;}`

UPDATE
Apparently, we're both just having one of those days. If you want to make the H1 truly SEO/Screen reader friendly, it would be better to do this with your CSS:

```
#header h1{
    width:XXXpx;
    hight:XXXpx;
    background:url('image/location.png');
    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This way your text is actually there on the page and rendered, it's just kind of off screen.

Comment: a better way would be to use an id/class for the h1 because other h1's would come up in the page and would end up hidden so something like 
`h1#hide{display:none;visible:hidden;}` What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's an error on my part. Thanks for catching that. Updated.
I avoid extra ids/classes whenever possible and use the flow of a document to dictate - but that's just a preference. Makes it easier to read and change later. :)

Comment: I'm stupified that I didn't think of this. Thank you. A side note, while on a simple page like mine it makes no difference - using classes or ids is much quicker than using recursive definitions. So `h1.hide` would be optimal, as `#header h1` takes a little bit longer to render (only really noticeable when there are thousands upon thousands of elements on the page)

Comment: Updated with more SEO/Screen reader friendly CSS. And yes it is one of those days. You technically dont need the H1 with the second CSS solution. /HOWEVER/ that H1 really helps with the SEO.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `#header` div with `h1` if you want this tag, set background image on said `h1` and even put some text in it (company name) and use `text-indent` to hide it.

Plus, in your quest to minimize number of elements you can use `body` as a wrapper, and if you need full page background just set in on `html` element.

Comment: I actually considered using `<body>` as a wrapper, but the ultimate site needs to have the content in a 960-pixel container in the center with a background image, then I want a solid color outside of this container. I didn't know how to do that other than apply the background color to `<body>` and the background image to `#wrapper`

Comment: Simply set the solid color on html, and background image on body: `html { bacground:defec8;} body {width:960px; background:url(img.jpg); margin:0 auto}`

Answer (score 1):

Set `display: none` on the H1 tag rather than the div, and use the background image on the div.